# MarkLogic insert document with options

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I'm trying to insert document with permissions. But I couldn't get permission to work with OPTIONS.  I'm sure `/doc/abc.xml` has permissions need copy over to `/example.xml`.

```
xdmp:document-insert(
   "/example.xml",
   <a>aaa</a>,
   <options xmlns="xdmp:document-insert">  
     <permissions>{
                      for $p in xdmp:document-get-permissions("/doc/abc.xml")
                      return
                            <permission>{$p}</permission>
                  }</permissions>
     <collections>{
       <collection>/my/additional/collection</collection>
    
  }</collections>
  <quality>10</quality>
</options>))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just return the permissions returned from [`xdmp:document-get-permissions()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-get-permissions) directly inside of the `<permissions>` element, without wrapping with a `<permission>` element:

```
<permissions>{ xdmp:document-get-permissions("/doc/abc.xml") }</permissions>
```